# Java http(s) client not failing

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Java SE desktop (console) application using the [Apache HTTP components](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) library:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpcore" rev="4.4.5"/>
```

At the lowest layer I am simply doing a:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

I am then using this console application to access a web service that is served over SSL and where the server is configured with the following certificate:

```
Common Name (CN)    InCommon RSA Server CA
Organization (O)    Internet2
Organizational Unit (OU)    InCommon
```

I was expecting my client to fail. This is because when I look at the certificates that come bundled with Java nothing with "internet2" or "inc" seems to be among them:

```
$ keytool -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts -list | grep -i 'internet2\|inc'
Enter keystore password:  
<no output>
$
```

Why is my client not failing? I have not configured it to accept all certificates. In the past (when the server was presenting no certificate at all) the code was indeed failing but I was expecting that with the new certificate the situation would remain the same as the InCommon CA is not listed among those found in Java's `cacerts` file.

Comment: Look at (if necessary add to Q) the complete chain offered by the server; since j7 keytool can do this for you with `keytool -printcert -sslserver hostname[:port]` . In particular crt.sh knows of 2 CA certs with names including the attributes you post (plus L=Ann Arbor, ST=MI, C=US), with slightly different validity and different sigalg, both under USERTrust RSA, which in turn is signed by both AddTrust External and Microsoft Code Ver, the former of which is trusted by all Suncle java versions I have.

Comment: Run HttpClient with full context logging as described here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html. HttpClient logs lots of SSL session details in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to use `keytool -printcert -sslserver hostname[:port]` was very useful.

It's still not very clear to me how to decipher the output of `keytool -printcert -sslserver` and how to "connect" it with the output of `keytool -printcert`. The following (brittle) incantation does find some matches:

```
for x in $(keytool -printcert -sslserver example.com:443 -v | grep ^Issuer | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c4- | sort | uniq); do keytool -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts -list   | grep -i $x; done
```

… however the matches are key-insensitive and on the prefix only.

In particular the output of `keytool -printcert -sslserver` has the string "USERTrust" but the closest that the output of `keytool -keystore` has is: "usertrusteccca" and "usertrustrsaca".

## output of `keytool -printcert -sslserver` (greping for `usertrust`)

```
$ keytool -printcert -sslserver example.com:443 -v | grep -i usertrust

 accessLocation: URIName: http://crt.usertrust.com/InCommonRSAServerCA_2.crt
 accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.usertrust.com
Owner: CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US
 accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.usertrust.com
 [URIName: http://crl.usertrust.com/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crl]
Issuer: CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority, O=The USERTRUST Network, L=Jersey City, ST=New Jersey, C=US
 accessLocation: URIName: http://crt.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA.crt
 accessLocation: URIName: http://ocsp.usertrust.com
 [URIName: http://crl.usertrust.com/USERTrustRSACertificationAuthority.crl]
```

## output of `keytool -keystore` (greping for `usertrust`)

```
$ keytool -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts -list   | grep -i usertrust
Enter keystore password:  

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

usertrusteccca, May 11, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
usertrustrsaca, May 11, 2015, trustedCertEntry,
```